# ClearCase create a web view with CAL or clearTool

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client, clearcase-automation

I need to create a **web view** on windows via **cleartool** or **CAL**, I know how to do it via ClearTeam explorer but I can't find the exact command that will perform the same with the same parameters I provide via the GUI:

**Parameters:**
view tag - view_tag
copy area path name - c:\temp\view_tag
server url - http://.../ccrc
user name
password

I tried a lot of `cleartool mkview` combinations but not luck so far

Answer (score 1):

The [rcleartool mkview command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkview.htm) does mention web views with:

```
rcleartool mkview [ –tag web-view-tag ] [ –tmo/de { insert_cr | transparent | strip_cr } ]
       [ –str/eam stream-selector ] copyarea
```

For a web view, it creates a copy area.

Again, this is using the [`rcleartool` (ClearCase remote client command-line interface )](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21594728), which means you will need to use first:

```
login [ –lna/me login-name ] [ –serv/er server–url ] [ –pas/sword password ]
      [ –proxy_lna/me proxy–login–name ] [ –proxy_pas/sword password ]
```

Comment: Thanks, But for some reason I installed ClearTeam Explorer but I got cleartool and not rcleartool, so I don't understand how can I get it

Comment: @Efrat What version of clearcase are you using? (type `cleartool -verall`)

Comment: it lists versions from 8.0.1.1 to 8.0.1.14

Comment: I fond the rcleartool.bat, but on the first try it doesn't find the **_JAVA_CMD_PATH_** , after I manualy put the path to java.exe it still doesn't manage to configure: `Error: Could not find or load main class org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main`